# Django 1.9.4 template inheritance does not work

Tags: python, django

I'm new Django user. In my new 1.9.4 project I created a new app called "personal". This is the app source tree:

```
personal
-templates
--personal
---main.html
---content.html
```

in personal/view.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'personal/main.html')
```

in main.html

```
<!doctype html>
  <html lang="en">
    <body>
     <p>Hi everyone!</p>
     {% block content %}
     {% endblock %}
    </body>
  </html>
```

in content.html

```
{% extends 'personal/main.html' %}

{% block content %}
<p>My personal content</p>
{% endblock %}
```

and finally my template settings in settings.py :

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

So when I start server, django renders only "Hi everyone" without extends the content block "My personal content".

Why?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You rendered the layout instead of the actual template. Your view should be:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'personal/content.html')
```